# Unable to populate drop down list inside gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I am binding a dropdownlist i have firstname in the 1st column and lastname as a DDL in the second column`

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{ 
    DataTable myTable = new DataTable();

    DataColumn productIDColumn = new DataColumn("FirstName");

    DataColumn productNameColumn = new DataColumn("LastName");

    myTable.Columns.Add(productNameColumn);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    ds = get();
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

   {

      var  fname= (e.Row.Cells[0].Text);

    var expression = "FirstName "+fname;

    DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

    DataRow[] rows = ds.Tables[0].Select(expression);



    ddl.DataSource = myTable;

    ddl.DataTextField = "LastName";

    ddl.DataValueField = "LastName";

    ddl.DataBind();

 }
```

but the ddl is empty unable to fill the ddl any help on this??

Comment: Is the first column getting populated correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, `myTable` has no data.

You are creating `myTable`, but you aren't filling it:  you are fetching info into the variable `ds`, and filtering it into `rows`, but you set `ddl.DataSource` to `myTable`, not to `rows`.

Use `rows` and you will probably be fine, as long as there is data in `rows`.

```
ddl.DataSource = rows;

ddl.DataTextField = "LastName"; 

ddl.DataValueField = "LastName"; 

ddl.DataBind();
```